# Need to improve my function that returns multiple SMAs at a point in time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have a function that returns SMA (Simple Moving Averages) SMA200, SMA50, SMA20 & SMA10 when I pass a typical OHLCV dataframe and also a parameter "retro_days". So if I pass **retro_days = 0**, it returns the 4 SMAs **as of today**. If I pass **retro_days = 10**, it returns the 4 SMAs **as of 10 trading days back**.

My problem is that it all works well in terms of accuracy, but when I loop through a number of Ticker Symbols, the time adds up for each Ticker Symbol and **this loop ends up taking a lot of time**. I call this function 6 times for each Ticker Symbol with retro_days as 20, 10, 5, 3, 1 & 0.

Can someone suggest a more efficient way in which I can achieve this? THANK YOU.

My function looks like this where **df_SMA** is being passed the **df_OHLCV** for the ticker.:

```
def get_SMA_Stats( df_SMA, retro_days):
    if retro_days > 0:
        df_SMA = df_SMA[ 0 : len( df_SMA)-retro_days]
        
    sma200 = df_SMA.Close.rolling( window = 200).mean()[ -1:][0]
    sma50 = df_SMA.Close.rolling( window = 50).mean()[ -1:][0]
    sma20 = df_SMA.Close.rolling( window = 20).mean()[ -1:][0]
    sma10 = df_SMA.Close.rolling( window = 10).mean()[ -1:][0]
    
    return sma200, sma50, sma20, sma10
```

The call to this function is as follows:

```
SMA200, SMA50, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 20)
SMA200, SMA50, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 10)
SMA200Tm5, SMA50Tm5, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 5)
SMA200Tm3, SMA50Tm3, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 3)
SMA200Tm1, SMA50Tm1, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 1)
SMA200, SMA50, SMA20, SMA10 = get_SMA_Stats( df_OHLCV, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve combining [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [discrete differences](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```py
def get_SMA(df, periods):
  '''
    step 1) compute the cumulative sum of the dataframe.
    step 2) compute the differences of the cumulative sum
    step 3) skip the of the first period
  '''
  return df.cumsum(axis=0).diff(periods=periods, axis=0).loc[periods:, :] / periods;

def get_SMA_Stats( df_SMA, retro_days):
    if retro_days > 0:
        df_SMA = df_SMA[ 0 : len( df_SMA)-retro_days]
        
    sma200 = get_SMA(df_SMA, 200)
    sma50 = get_SMA(df_SMA, 50)
    sma20 = get_SMA(df_SMA, 20)
    sma10 = get_SMA(df_SMA, 10)
    
    return sma200, sma50, sma20, sma10
```

In one test with a dataframe with one million rows and 10 columns the function `get_SMA_stats` took 0.3 s here.