# How do I update 3 columns of dataframe A with 3 respective columns of dataframe B with one np.where statement

Tags: dataframe, numpy, array-broadcasting

In the code below, I have created **df_d** that has daily data and a **df_i** that has intraday data with 5 min intervals.

I have 3 columns in **df_d** (**Volume, Volume1 and Volume2**) that I want to propagate to **df_i** for respective dates.

The code achieves the result when I call `df_i, df_d = main_process()`. However, when I run it on large data, this takes up lot of time.

How can I update the 3 columns of df_i with just one np.where statement? Or for that matter, what is the fastest way to achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

def dt_to_integer( dt_time):
    return 10000*dt_time.year + 100*dt_time.month + dt_time.day

def main_process():
 
    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    index = pd.date_range( todays_date, periods=5, freq='D')
     
    columns = [ 'Volume', 'Volume1', 'Volume2']
     
    df_d = pd.DataFrame( index=index, columns=columns)
    df_d[ 'Volume'] = df_d.index.day * 100
    df_d[ 'Volume1'] = df_d.index.day * 500
    df_d[ 'Volume2'] = df_d.index.day * 1000

    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    index = pd.date_range( todays_date, periods=1440, freq='5min')
     
    columns = [ 'Volume', 'Volume1', 'Volume2']
     
    df_i = pd.DataFrame( index=index, columns=columns)
    df_i = df_i.loc[ df_i.index.isin( df_i.between_time('09:30:00', '16:00:00').index)]
     
    for i in range( len( df_d)):
        the_date = dt_to_integer( df_d.index[i])
        
        df_i.Volume = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_date, df_d.Volume[ i], df_i.Volume)
        df_i.Volume1 = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_date, df_d.Volume1[ i], df_i.Volume1)
        df_i.Volume2 = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_date, df_d.Volume2[ i], df_i.Volume2)
        
    return df_i, df_d

df_i, df_d = main_process()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987285/need-to-improve-my-function-that-returns-multiple-smas-at-a-point-in-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for your update `for i in range(len( df_d))`  you are update the full data frame for each iteration, so your complexity is `n1 * n2`. What can be done to improve the results is to use [numpy.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the insertion indices for the values in `df_d`  into `df_i`, then update `df_i` in the positions where the inserted index is the same as the existing index.

```py
def main_process2(n1=5, n2=1440):
 
    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    index = pd.date_range( todays_date, periods=5, freq='D')
     
    columns = [ 'Volume', 'Volume1', 'Volume2']
     
    df_d = pd.DataFrame( index=index, columns=columns)
    df_d[ 'Volume'] = df_d.index.day * 100
    df_d[ 'Volume1'] = df_d.index.day * 500
    df_d[ 'Volume2'] = df_d.index.day * 1000

    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    index = pd.date_range( todays_date, periods=1440, freq='5min')
     
    columns = [ 'Volume', 'Volume1', 'Volume2']
     
    df_i = pd.DataFrame( index=index, columns=columns)
    df_i = df_i.loc[ df_i.index.isin( df_i.between_time('09:30:00', '16:00:00').index)]
    
    the_dates = np.sort(dt_to_integer(df_d.index))
    the_indices = np.searchsorted(the_dates, dt_to_integer(df_i.index))
    # will give IndexError df_d has an index not present in df_i
    df_i.Volume = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_dates[the_indices], df_d.Volume[the_indices], df_i.Volume)
    df_i.Volume1 = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_dates[the_indices], df_d.Volume1[the_indices], df_i.Volume1)
    df_i.Volume2 = np.where( dt_to_integer( df_i.index) == the_dates[the_indices], df_d.Volume2[the_indices], df_i.Volume2)

    return df_i, df_d
```

#### Correctness

I tested the output with

```
df_i, df_d = main_process()
df_i2, df_d2 = main_process2()
assert(np.max(np.abs(np.array(df_d) - np.array(df_d2))) == 0)
assert(np.max(np.abs(np.array(df_i) - np.array(df_i2))) == 0)
```

#### Aternatives

A slightly different implementation

```py
    # will give IndexError df_d has an index not present in df_i
    df_i.Volume[the_updated]  = np.array(df_d.Volume[the_indices[the_updated]])
    df_i.Volume1[the_updated] = np.array(df_d.Volume1[the_indices[the_updated]])
    df_i.Volume2[the_updated] = np.array(df_d.Volume2[the_indices[the_updated]])
```

Or a one linear updating all columns at once

```py
    df_i.iloc[the_updated, :] = df_d.iloc[the_indices[the_updated], :]
```

#### Performance

After the proposed change, `main_process2(50, 14400)`, input 10x larger than your example, runs in 10-15 milliseconds, whyile `main_process(50, 14400)` would run in about 13.5 seconds.